# regex capturing group/alternative combination not working in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use this expression:

```
var reg = "/(jan|feb|mar)[A-z]*\[0-9]/"
```

to capture at least the first three letters of the month(or more letters) plus a digit. This does not work however. When I remove the parenthesis, it works but then the [A-z]*[0-9] bit only aplies to march. Please help, thanks.

Comment: You need `var reg = /(?:jan|feb|mar)[a-z]*[0-9]/i;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect, also the regex should not be a string.

Use regex `/(jan|feb|mar)[a-z]*[0-9]/i`

Regex explanation: https://regex101.com/r/9Qv2dy/2

Snippet:

```js
var reg = /(jan|feb|mar)[a-z]*[0-9]/i;

console.log('January1'.match(reg));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains several issues.

1. The `/.../` regex literal should not be put inside quotes.
2. [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970), you need `[A-Za-z]`
3. A `\[` pattern matches a literal `[` char. To match a digit, you need `[0-9]` or `\d`. To match 1 or more digits: `[0-9]+` or `\d+`.

Use

```
var reg = /(?:jan|feb|mar)[a-z]*[0-9]/i;
```

See JS demo:

```js
var reg = /(?:jan|feb|mar)[a-z]*[0-9]/i;
console.log("Date: January1".match(reg));
```

Comment: I dint get the significance of having `?:` in the regex, I have never used that myself

Comment: @RahulDesai See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) about non-capturing groups.